# Perl code executed alongside C program writes incorrect byte length to memory in Windows

Tags: c, perl, buffer-overflow

**Disclaimer: i'm not worried about the syntax.**

While learning about buffer overflows, I'm playing around with Perl code executed alongside my C program to demonstrate how the overflow works. However, when I input the code `.\Buffer $(perl -e 'print "A"x16 . "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"')` it only adds the `$(perl` to the first buffer in memory, `buffer_two` as shown here:

```
.\Buffer $(perl -e 'print "A"x16 . "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"')

[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains two
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains one
[BEFORE] value is at 0061FF1C and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 6 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains $(perl
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains one
[AFTER] value is at 0061FF1C and is 5 (0x00000005)
```

The bytes between `buffer_two` and `value` is **16 bytes** (`(gdb) print 0x0061ff1c - 0x0061ff0c $1 = 16`), so I print "A" 16 times to fill the space. However, what should happen is the text following `"A"x16` should overwrite the next memory address(es). When used on Linux, the code works fine, and I get the following output:

```
./Buffer $(perl -e 'print "A"x16 . "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"')
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ffca168185c and contains two
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ffca1681864 and contains one
[BEFORE] value is at 0x7ffca168186c and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 20 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0x7ffca168185c and contains AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ�
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0x7ffca1681864 and contains AAAAAAAAﾭ�
[AFTER] value is at 0x7ffca168186c and is -559038737 (0xdeadbeef)
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int value = 5;
char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8]; //create two buffers of 8 bytes

strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); //copy strings one and two into buffers
strcpy(buffer_two, "two");

printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_two, buffer_two); //print initial address and value
printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);

printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1])); //copy first argument digits into buffer two

//if((int *)argv[1] > (int *)8) //test if argument input is greater than 8 bytes
//{
    //printf("[!!] Buffer error\n\n");
    //exit(-1); 
//}

strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);

printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains %s\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);

}
```

**While writing this post I notice it states only 6 bytes are being written, which I'm unsure as to why.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `.\Buffer $(perl -e 'print "A"x16 . "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"')`

This syntax (run command in parenthesis and replace `$(...)` with its output) is a feature of (many) UNIX shells.

Whatever shell you are using on Windows clearly doesn't do that.

Comment: that makes sense! I should've considered that, I'll just have to find the correct syntax for CMD.

Comment: @ExploitedOptic Or use a _real_ shell.

Comment: what shell would you recommend on Windows? I can use Linux, I just don't wanna always run a VM to do code.

Comment: You could use `bash` from cygwin. Note that you no longer need to run a VM to use Linux on Windows -- WSL2 works very nicely for command-line utilities.

Comment: WSL2 is a VM, lol :) But it's very well integrated.